# How to do session management between two applications?

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, session-management

I am trying to place view pages and controllers in app-1 and place the business logic in app-2. To export the business logic we used REST. When a request comes from browser it will hit the app-1 and app-1 communicate with app-2 through REST links. For every request from app-1 to app-2 treated as new request. How can i maintain the session between app-1 and app-2 after app login.

Comment: same as any http session. A token for example.

Comment: Your both application running on single server or multiple server ??

Comment: both applications running on different servers

Answer (score 0):

You can have a login rest call that returns a key with the session on App2 server. That key must be sent in the next calls for validating the sender.

Another thought, all calls go throught App1 so controlling the session on App1 is enough. If session is expired on App1 no calls are made to App2.

If what you need is sharing the session data, you'll need another mechanism to sync them in both servers.